# How can we implement a reusable focus manager for web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, focus

I'm working on some web pages used to do massive input. the interfaces have many controls and due to the users habits, `focus` should be set to the next control by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

Actually I'm using a classical approach implemented with `jQuery` like this

```
    $('#txtInput1').keypress(
            function(event) {
               if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                      $('#txtInput2').focus();
               }
     });

    $('#txtInput2').keypress(
            function(event) {
               if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                   $.getJSON('Ajax/getSomeResult.aspx', 
                             {'param': $(this).val() }, function(data) {
                         if (data['msg'] != "")
                              $('#txtInput3').focus();
                         else 
                              $('#txtInput4').focus();
                    });
                }
    });

    $('#txtInput4').keypress(
            function(event) {
               if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                      $('#txtInput5').focus();
               }
     });
```

As you can see the same code structure is repeated for each input control except some of them when we need to do extra work before we can determine who is the next control to jump to

My question is: how can we refactor this code in order to have a solution that can work for all pages with a little or no repetition if possible?

Take in minde that the condition

```
  $.getJSON(
       'Ajax/getSomeResult.aspx', 
       {'param': $(this).val() }, 
       function(data) {
          if (data['msg'] != "")
              $('#txtInput3').focus();
          else 
              $('#txtInput4').focus();
  });
```

is just an example; it can be anything that can let us choose the next control who need the `focus`

Answer (score 1):

Use the "unobtrusive" approach. Add your own attributes to the input elements, like `data-focus-next="txt2" data-post-url="/whatever"`, then use those attributes as jQuery selectors to add events on documentReady.

Add more attributes to control the next control based on the JSON response, for example `data-post-success-focus="txt3" data-post-fail-focus="txt4"`.

For per-page customization (if needed) you can even define the JS function name to be called as an attribute, like `data-on-post="txt4OnPost"`.

Comment: Is the `custom attribut` feature specific to HTML5?

Comment: No, HTML5 defined them but they also work in HTML4. You *will* get a warning when using XHTML4 validators though, but they will work. It's how the whole "unobtrusive" approach in MVC3 is implemented.

Comment: Seems to be more intrusive than the approach i posted in the question

Comment: Suit yourself. Custom attributes enable you to do stuff declaratively (as in "what it should do"), rather than imperatively (as in "how it should do it"). That way you can truly separate and reuse the code, and I don't see how is that more intrusive than selecting elements by IDs or classes and harcoding the behavior. When you select by ID you're limited to one element, with CSS classes you are limited to all elements of the class, but only with custom attributes you can also define parameters (like URL for post, for example).

Comment: Custom attributes are definitely unobtrusive and way more flexible imo. I like this answer

Answer (score 0):

**No Repetition** needed! Use it this way:

```
$('input[id*="txtInput"]').keypress(
    function(event) {
       if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          next = $(this).attr('id').substr($(this).attr('id').length-1);
          $('#txtInput' + next).focus();
       }
   }
);
```

In case you use classes, please try this:

```
$('input[class*="txtInput"]').keypress(
    function(event) {
       if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          if($(this).hasClass('theAjaxCondition'))
          {
              $.getJSON('Ajax/getSomeResult.aspx', 
                  {'param': $(this).val() }, function(data) {
                  if (data['msg'] != "")
                      $('.txtInput' + next).focus();
                  else 
                      $('.txtInput' + next + 1).focus();
              });
           } else {
               next = $(this).attr('class').substr($(this).attr('class').length-1);
               $('.txtInput' + next).focus();
           }
       }
   }
);
```

In the HTML for this input, you would need to give 
Hope it helps! :)

Comment: txtInput is just an example, inputs have different name and we don't always jump to the next input some time we jump to the next, some times we skip three or four control and so on

Comment: This doesn't take the condition into account.

Comment: @anouar204 In that case, give some classes. Add a class named this way, considering it like a tab stop. Check the code now, it works for any page with just the naming.

Comment: As @MarcelKorpel mentioned your solution does not take the condition into account. take a look at `$('#txtInput2').keypress`

Comment: Hey, in that case, let me edit the code a little bit. Might be kind of getting complicated.

Comment: Not sure, but will this update help? Adding a new class for certain condition. :)

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough, i edited my post take a look now

Comment: I took that too. Did you see my updated answer? When you give the text input a class, then you will be able to execute that condition too. But such conditions need to be written specific.

Comment: Look for somthing that take this also into consideration

Comment: @anouar204 Did you check out: `if($(this).hasClass('theAjaxCondition'))` line? Won't this solve?

Comment: a condition can also be somthing like  `if(somevariable=1) jumpToInputX else if(somevariable=2) jumpToInputY else jumpToInputZ`

Comment: That's what I said. Group types of conditions into classes. One having `AJAX`, one to be `Null`, etc. See this is the maximum I can think of, but it does makes some re-usability.